# Move multiple selected files into specific folder

Tags: c#, directory, openfiledialog, fileinfo

I have implemented a code like this from which I got the idea somewhere.

```
public string BrowseFolder()
{
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse EXCEL File";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    }

    return null;
}


public void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name.ToString());

        // Copy the file.
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            // Create the subdirectory.
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

            // Copy the subdirectories.
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok let's assume that this two methods is in a class. I have easily understood how this codes work. It is copying all the files inside the folder I browse. This is not what I need. What I wanted to achieve is to copy only the selected files (multiple) in my folder.

I've tried to manipulate my code but I still didn't get the right solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The FileNames (plural) property will have the paths of the files to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
{
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    fInfo.MoveTo(newFilePath);
}
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the files selected from OpenFileDialog like this:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] filesSelected = openFileDialog1.FileNames;    
}
```

The code above returns all the files that a user selected from the OpenFileDialog.